# Parse an array in KSH shell?

Tags: arrays, linux, unix, ksh

i'm a newbie to shell coding. My intention is to accept arguments from the command line, in CSV format, parse the input into an array. Something like,

```
sh scriptname.sh 123,345,456,789...
```

123,345,456..should be stored into an array.
So far, i have acheived the following,

```
#!/bin/ksh
#get the argument to be parsed
RID=$1
#Parse the argument, remove the space and store into and variable
str=`echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g'
#Assign the value to a variable
set  -A RIDS $str
#Get the count of arguments in the array
num=${#RIDS[@]}
echo $num
#Display the elements in the array
i=0
while [ $num -gt 0 ] do
echo ${A_RIDS[i]}
i=`expr $1 + 1`
num=`expr $num - 1`
done
```

But it throws an error as "Bad substitution" (at line7)

Alternatively I have tried in the following way (doing it in a single shot)like the below

```
set -A A_RID $(echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g')
```

instead of

```
str=`echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g'
set  -A RIDS $str
```

This time it shows "unexpected token '(' on the line of

```
set -A A_RID $(echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g').
```

Can you tell where i'm doing it wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a backtick when assigning to `str`, try `str=\`echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g'\`` (note the backtick at end of the line)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, works for me. What version of ksh do you have?

```
$ ksh
$ RID=123,345,456,789
$ set -A A_RID $(echo $RID | sed 's/,/\ /g')
$ printf "%s\n" "${A_RID[@]}"
123
345
456
789
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

Depending on your ksh version, it can be as short as

```
IFS=, read -A A_RID <<< "$RID"
```

Comment: Hi,sorry for the delayed response. The problem is still persisiting for me. I'm not sure why the code is not runnig for me!When i try to run    read -A A_RID << "$RID" , it says -A is not an identifier. I'm running shell via PuTTY on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

By starting your script by

```
sh scriptname.sh 123,345,456,789...
```

you let `sh` execute it, not `ksh`. Set execute permission on `scriptname.sh` and type just

```
scriptname.sh 123,345,456,789...
```

to have it executed by `/bin/ksh`. Then you can apply yourself to errors not coming from using the wrong shell.

Besides, you should revert your edit of your question where you removed a needed backtick.